# Does ontology study "being qua being"?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, aristotle, being

May I say that ontology studies "being qua being", while the sciences study "entity qua entity" ?

I ask this because I don't understand how ontology could study the "entity qua entity", taking into account that the sciences study  all the entities and their properties, as we can observe in chemistry and physics, for example.

Comment: I made some edits which you may roll back or continue editing. Welcome to Philosophy!

Comment: As for many philosophical terms, it is hard to have a clearcut definition of [Ontology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-ontology/#Ont) : "As a first approximation, ontology is the study of what there is." A modern approach to ontology is based on the connection with logic; see e.g. Nino Cocchiarella, [Formal Ontology and Conceptual Realism, (Springer, 2007)](https://books.google.it/books?id=yWh2gbkG-_8C&pg=PR4).

Comment: I'd agree with your thinking. The trouble is, as Heidegger notes, even philosophers tend to study 'beings' rather than 'Being'. . ,

Comment: See [The Subject Matter of Aristotle’s Metaphysics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-metaphysics/#SubjMattArisMeta) for comemnts on Aristotle’s description "the study of being qua being’".

Comment: Don't chemistry and physics only study *physical* and *chemical* properties of entities, and not properties of entities *as such*? It might help to explain what "qua" means to you, this Aristotelian term is very vague and antiquated. Aristotle himself at places denies that "science of being qua being" is possible, see [The Oxford Handbook of Aristotle](http://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780195187489.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780195187489-e-14).

Comment: On the other side, what you call "entity qua entity" I would just point out the chief characteristic of no necessity, no connection back (causation) and no development forward, idea of ends, or at least of development. This means no narrative. Hume, Boltzmann. I am trying to give a little history. To Russell's credit, he wrote such books as "The Limits of Empiricism"; here is a link you may find helpful: https://www.csus.edu/indiv/n/nogalesp/phil176spg06/russell/russellandmetaphysics.doc